# What Nifty 50 ETFS in India allows covered calls?

Tags: india, etf, covered-call, covered-call-writing

I want to buy a Nifty ETF such as [SBI-ETF Nifty 50](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/SETFNIF50:NSE) or [Nippon India ETF Nifty BeES](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/NIFTYBEES:NSE) but I am not able to figure out if these ETFs allow for covered calls to be written. Can members guide me which of these (or similar) ETFs allows for covered call writing?

Comment: why it is off topic ?, user is simply asking what ETFs has options available, given it is a developing country, less common people knows so in my opinion, this question should remain open.